# Replacing undeclared variables in C# code with an invoke

Tags: c#, roslyn

Continuation of ([Replace all variables in C# code with methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798188/replace-all-variables-in-c-sharp-code-with-methods))

I need to replace all the undeclared variables in a piece of C# code with an indexer expression. For example the code:

```
var b = 28;
return a + b;
```

needs to be converted into:

```
var b = 28;
return _resolver["a"] + b;
```

The `_resolver` object has a string indexer which returns a `dynamic`. Of course this may still fail at runtime, but I want to get to the point where it at least compiles.

I've got it working for 'isolated' variables like in the example above, but it fails when a method or property on the undeclared variable is called. For example:

```
return a.FavouriteColour;
```

throws an exception in the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` class. I'm probably making a syntax node substitution I'm not supposed to make, but I don't see how I should do it differently.

My rewriter code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

namespace RoslynConfusion
{
  public static class UndeclaredReplacement
  {
    public static string ReplaceUndeclared(string code)
    {
      var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
      var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Test", new[] { tree }, References);
      var rewriter = new UndeclaredRewriter(compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree));

      var root = tree.GetRoot();
      root = rewriter.Visit(root);

      return root.SyntaxTree.ToString();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MetadataReference> References
    {
      get
      {
        yield return MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(int).Assembly.Location);
      }
    }
    private sealed class UndeclaredRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
    {
      private readonly SemanticModel _model;
      public UndeclaredRewriter(SemanticModel model)
      {
        _model = model ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
      }

      public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
      {
        var nodeʹ = base.VisitIdentifierName(node);
        var symbol = _model.GetSymbolInfo(node);

        // We only care about *undeclared* identifiers...
        if (symbol.Symbol != null) return nodeʹ;
        if (symbol.CandidateSymbols.Any()) return nodeʹ;

        // ... and we don't care about unknown method invokes either.
        var parent = nodeʹ.Parent;
        if (parent.IsKind(SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression))
          return nodeʹ;

        return CreateResolverSyntax(node.Identifier);
      }
      private SyntaxNode CreateResolverSyntax(SyntaxToken token)
      {
        var literal = LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, Literal(token.ToString()));
        var indexSyntax = BracketedArgumentList(SingletonSeparatedList(Argument(literal)));
        var resolveSyntax = ElementAccessExpression(IdentifierName("_resolver"), indexSyntax);
        return resolveSyntax;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my test method with two failing cases:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUndeclaredReplacement()
    {
      var replaced = RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared("return a;");
      Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "return _resolver[\"a\"];");

      replaced = RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared("return a + b;");
      Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "return _resolver[\"a\"]+ _resolver[\"b\"];");

      replaced = RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared("return System.Math.Abs(a);");
      Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "return System.Math.Abs(_resolver[\"a\"]);");

      // The following fail with exception:
      // Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ElementAccessExpressionSyntax'
      // to type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax'.
      replaced = RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared("return a.Length;");
      Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "return _resolver[\"a\"].FavouriteColour;");

      replaced = RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared("return a.Function(b);");
      Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "return _resolver[\"a\"].Function(_resolver[\"b\"]);");
    }
```

Call stack for the exception:

```
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitMemberAccessExpression(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node) Line 1519  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberAccessExpressionSyntax.Accept<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxVisitor<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode> visitor) Line 1352   C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.Visit(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode node) Line 41  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitReturnStatement(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ReturnStatementSyntax node) Line 1801    C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ReturnStatementSyntax.Accept<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxVisitor<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode> visitor) Line 7021  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.Visit(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode node) Line 41  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitGlobalStatement(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.GlobalStatementSyntax node) Line 1753    C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.GlobalStatementSyntax.Accept<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxVisitor<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode> visitor) Line 5970  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.Visit(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode node) Line 41  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitListElement<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberDeclarationSyntax>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberDeclarationSyntax node) Line 168 C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitList<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberDeclarationSyntax>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxList<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberDeclarationSyntax> list) Line 145 C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitCompilationUnit(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax node) Line 1882    C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax.Accept<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode>(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxVisitor<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode> visitor) Line 9061  C#
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.Visit(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode node) Line 41  C#
    Grasshopper2.dll!RoslynConfusion.UndeclaredReplacement.ReplaceUndeclared(string code) Line 21   C#
    Grasshopper2Tests.dll!Grasshopper2Test.ExpressionTests.TestUndeclaredReplacement() Line 31  C#
    [External Code] 
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Extensions.MethodInfoExtensions.InvokeAsSynchronousTask(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo, object classInstance, object[] parameters) Line 158  C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodInfo.ExecuteInternal.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 276    C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(System.Action action) Line 75 C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodInfo.ExecuteInternal(object[] arguments) Line 277 C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodInfo.Invoke(object[] arguments) Line 129  C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute.Execute(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ITestMethod testMethod) Line 102    C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodRunner.ExecuteTest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodInfo testMethodInfo) Line 404   C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodRunner.RunTestMethod() Line 219   C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestMethodRunner.Execute() Line 157 C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.UnitTestRunner.RunSingleTest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.ObjectModel.TestMethod testMethod, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> testContextProperties) Line 98    C#
    [External Code]
```

[image: exceptioncallstack]

Comment: What’s the exception?

Comment: @DanielA.White "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ElementAccessExpressionSyntax' to type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax'."

Comment: please provide the whole stack - int the question itself

Comment: Given that there's no limit to how intricate the expressions might become, consider a simpler rewrite approach where you inject the variable in the containing scope (so the moral equivalent of `dynamic a = _resolver["a"]`) and then let the remainder fall into place on its own.

Comment: @JeroenMostert interesting idea. I'm afraid it has issues of its own, as I need to know _when_ an undeclared variable is used. The object which contains this code must be recomputed if that undeclared variable (whose value is defined elsewhere) changes. However it may be acceptable for a recomputation to happen even if the code doesn't actually use the variable, for example if it's in the wrong part of a conditional.

It certainly sounds like a way forward in the meantime, thanks.